# How can I get User's facebook id on fan page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

with Facebook C# sdk I read signed_request and have following details

```
if (Request.Params["signed_request"] != null)
            {
                dynamic signedRequest = fb.ParseSignedRequest(ConfigHelper.FacebookAppSecret,
                                                              Request.Params["signed_request"]);   

Session["signedRequest"] = signedRequest.ToString();

                if (signedRequest.page != null)
                {
                    requestFromFanPage = true;
                    var lPid = signedRequest.page.id != null ? (string) signedRequest.page.id : "";
                    Session["lPid"] = lPid.ToString();
                    var lLiked = signedRequest.page.liked ?? "";
                    Session["lLiked"] = lLiked;
                    userLiked = lLiked;
                }   

                var userid = signedRequest.user_id ?? "";    
                Session["lUserId"] =  userid;    
            }
```

and I get following result without Facebook id :(

```
{"algorithm":"HMAC-SHA256","issued_at":1370416053,"page":{"id":"490007204401534","liked":true,"admin":false},"user":{"country":"au","locale":"en_US","age":{"min":21}}}
```

I need facebookuserid , Is there any way that I can get it with out getting permission?

Comment: Seems your app is not authorized by User. You get `User Id` in `signedRequest` if user authorized your app.

Comment: It's a tab page and how can I ask user to authorise my app?

Comment: You will be required to implement the [Login](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/) so that user can authorize your application.